# discord.js v12 / 'must be 2048 or fewer characters in length'

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

i'm having 'trouble' with the formatting since the current guild that i'm specficially making this bot for has too many bans for the bot to format, hence the error being that it must be '2048 or fewer characters in length',

the code works only if the characters don't exceed that length.

can anyone help?

```
const { MessageEmbed, Message } = require('discord.js');

module.exports.run = async(client, message, args, getMember) => {
    if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) return;

    message.guild.fetchBans()
    .then(bans => {
        const obj = bans.map(c => ({
            user: `__${c.user.tag}__ — (${c.user.id})`
        }));

        const blist = Array.from(obj);
        if ( blist.length < 1 ) return message.channel.send(new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#030303')
        .setDescription(`there are no banned users — ${message.guild.name}`))
        let index = 0;

        message.channel.send({
            embed: new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`ban list`)
            .setDescription(`${blist.map(bl => bl.user).join('\n')}`)
            .setColor('#030303')
            .setTimestamp()
        })
    })
}

module.exports.config = {
    name: 'fetchbans',
    aliases: ["bans", "fb"]
}
```

Comment: You'd need to either send multiple messages or paginate the one list

Comment: i'm quite a beginner to this, i know what paginating is but doing it is what i don't know, could you help in any way?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you need to split your large text into multiple parts and then you can use pagination to cycle through them.

So to make this work we will start with spliting the text. One way of doing that is to split the entire text into an array and then split that array into chunks of 2048 characters.

```
const text = "some text"; // this is your large text.
const array = text.split(''); // here we split the text with each char being a new element.
const largeArray = []; // this is the array we will place the batches in.

var i, j, temparray, chunk = 2048; // here we define some variables and also the length of each batch.
// now we iterate over the array and split it into the defined batches
// then we join them back together and place them in the new array
for (i = 0, j = array.length; i < j; i += chunk) {
    temparray = array.slice(i, i + chunk);
    largeArray.push(temparray.join(''));
}
```

Now we have an array with each element being 2048 characters or less. Now we need to create a page parser. The way we do this here is with reactions. So first we need to create a function which handles our reactions.

```
// this needs to be an async function since we need to await the reactions
// using the author here ensures that only the person who sends the command
// can leaf through the pages
async function reactMessage(message, author, time, validReactions) {
    // the time is converted to milliseconds
    time *= 1000;

    // now we cycle through the valid reactions and add them to the message
    for (const reaction of validReactions) await message.react(reaction);

    // now we use a reaction filter to grab the used reaction
    const filter = (reaction, user) => validReactions.includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === author.id;
    
    // here we return the reaction used
    return message
        .awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: time })
        .then(collected => collected.first() && collected.first().emoji.name);
}
```

Now that we have a function to handle our reactions for us we need to create a function that handles the pagination. This function will use the previous function to create the needed reactions. This is a larger one so stay with me. Basically what this does is take an iterator and the array length, react to the message with the needed reaction and return the iterator to be used again.

```
async function pageParser(message, msg, i, time, chooseArr, array_length) {
    // create the reaction arrays for the first and last pages
    const chooseArrfirst = [chooseArr[1], chooseArr[2]];
    const chooseArrlast = [chooseArr[0], chooseArr[1]];

    // this part handles the first page
    if (i === 0) {
        var reaction = await reactMessage(msg, message.author, time, chooseArrfirst);

        if (reaction === chooseArr[2]) {
            msg.delete();
            i++;
            return i;
        } else if (reaction === chooseArr[1]) {
            i = array_length + 1;
            msg.delete();
            return;
        }
    // this part handles the last page
    } else if (i === array_length - 1) {
        var reaction = await reactMessage(msg, message.author, time, chooseArrlast);

        if (reaction === chooseArr[0]) {
            msg.delete();
            i--;
            return i;
        } else if (reaction === chooseArr[1]) {
            i = array_length + 1;
            msg.delete();
            return;
        }
    // this part handles the pages in the middle
    } else {
        var reaction = await reactMessage(msg, message.author, time, chooseArr);

        if (reaction === chooseArr[0]) {
            msg.delete();
            i--;
            return i;
        } else if (reaction === chooseArr[2]) {
            msg.delete();
            i++;
            return i;
        } else if (reaction === chooseArr[1]) {
            i = array_length + 1;
            msg.delete();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Great! Now that we have all the components that we need lets put them together.
First we create the iterator and the array with the reactions.

```
var i = 0; // this is the iterator
var a = true;
const chooseArr = ['◀', '⏹', '▶']; // these are the reactions in order
```

Now we use a `while` loop to make sure that the  pages get updated. Remember that `largeArray` from earlier? Now we need that again. We create an embed and set the description to the iterators index in the array. This updates the description. Then we can send the message and use our `pageParser` function.

```
while (a && i < largeArray.length) {
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription(largeArray[i])

    // since our function returns something, the iterator, we need to overwrite
    // the previous iterator
    i = await message.channel.send(embed).then(msg => pageParser(message, msg, i, 240000, chooseArr, largeArray.length))
}
```